# In wandb I always have this error: JobID 2925027: Could not read info

Tags: python, pytorch, jobs, wandb

I am using wandb (version  0.15.2) with Pytorch (2.0.1) and I am always having this error:

```
JobID 2925027: Could not read info.
```

I don't know where it comes from and how to solve it.

Comment: What makes you so sure it's wandb? (aka "remember to create a [mcve] so that you _know_ what's at fault" and can ask others to run the same code and get the same result, if you don't find the problem yourself already while reducing your code to minimal reproducible form. Which is usually what happens when you force yourself to run through that exercise)